# Can AutoHotKey intercept a mouse click?

Tags: autohotkey

aI use AutoHotKey to remap a few keys, and that has been extremely useful. Example:

```
!t::
        Send, ^t
return
```

That would intercept `Alt-t` key and send `Ctrl-t` instead.

I was wondering if there's a way to intercept an `Alt-LeftMouseClick` and send `Ctrl-LeftMouseClick` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This maps ALT+LeftMouseClick to Ctrl+LeftMouseClick**

```
!lbutton::send ^{click}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I could do it with:

```
!LButton::
        Send, {Control down}
        MouseClick
        Send, {Control up}
return
```